# How to query posts by month based on date custom field?

Tags: custom-field, filters, query, date, order

I currently created a custom field for a custom post type that stores a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy is there a way to query the posts by the month?

I "kind of" got the functionality I need using the following query:

`query_posts('post_type=attraction&meta_key=attraction_date&meta_value=10&meta_compare=LIKE');`

The `meta_value` parameter would be the month but since I'm using `LIKE` to compare if I have a date like 10/04/2011 it'd be returned even though it's not from october.

I know there's a `RLIKE` expression in MySQL that lets you use regex for the `LIKE` condition but I'm not sure if wordpress lets you use it in any way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you're using as a comparison, but `WP Query` supports meta query comparisons and even has a DATE type.

For example:

```
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 
                       'post_type' => 'attraction',
                       'meta_key' => 'attraction_date', 
                       'meta_value' => '10', 
                       'meta_compare' => 'LIKE', 
                       'type' => 'DATE' ) );
```

Using `10` is not going to get you very far, you should use a timestamp.

I have not tested the date parameter in WP QUERY, it should be using/converting all dates to a unix timestamp using `strtotime`, if not I would suggest doing so.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: I see, so in theory do you think if I use something like: `meta_value = strtotime('october')` and keep the rest the same it should work? I can't test right now but I'll make sure to give it a try once I get home

Comment: In theory yes, but I would check out the default `DATE` first.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work but I had an idea, since I need to query by the month and the custom field format is dd/mm/yyyy what I did was `'meta_value' => '/10/'` this way it wouldn't return posts with 10 as the day or if the year was 2010

Comment: You should use a variable for `'meta_value' => $my_date`, like `$my_date = strotime($whatever)`

Comment: I did I'm using the 10 as an example but I'm getting the value as a get parameter like `$my_date = strtotime($_GET['month'])` where the month equals to january, february or any other but it didn't work event when I set the type as `DATE`.